# How to wait for subscribe to finish Angular 5?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angular-observable

I am working on an Angular 5 app. I get an error because I have a function that executes before another function is done, hence getting a null variable. I have tried to use .map and .subscribe with Observable, but didn't succeed. Here is the code:

loadData is called from my **app.component class**:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.loadData(sessionStorage.getItem(...);
}
```

While that function executes, another function from **data.component class** (dataService.getData) is called on initialization:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataTxt = this.dataService.getData(...);
}
```

Here is the **data.service class:**

```
loadData(... : void) {
    if (sessionStorage["data"] == null {
        this.http.request(...)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
            ...
            sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.data));
            ...
        }
    }
}

getData(... : string){
    if (this.data == null) {
        this.data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["data"]);
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that **sessionStorage["data"]** is null until loadData() is done and I get this error a few times:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I understand that if I want to wait for subscribe to finish, I have to put the code that need to wait (getData()) just after the subscribe call. But the function that needs to wait is called from other classes so how do I put it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're mistaken that you'd put your code "after" the subscribe handler, you'd need to put it INSIDE of the subscribe handler, but regardless,

you need to use a subject of some kind here, probably a `ReplaySubject` in this particular case...

```
private dataSource = new ReplaySubject(1) // create a private subject
data$ = this.dataSource.asObservable() // and a public observable

loadData(... : void) {
    if (sessionStorage["data"] == null {
        this.http.request(...)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
            ...
            sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.data));
            this.dataSource.next(data) // set the data in the subject
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

then you'd subscribe to the subject in your component...

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.pipe(first()) // avoid memory leak.
      .subscribe(data => this.dataTxt = data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved the main problem. But there is still an error though. Because as stated, the getData() function in the data.service class is called from other classes too. So, I have several components which call the getData() function several times. When these components are used, the error is present again. Do I have to subscribe on every function in all the components that are using the getData function? (There are many). Or could I just do something with the getData function, so it waits for the loadData function to finish?

Comment: Nothing should use that get data function. Anything interested in the data should subscribe to it.