# Subscribe to one observable twice from a component doesn't work

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular5, rxjs5

I got several components subscribing to my data service and they are all working fine. But in one of my components, I try to subscribe twice (inside ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit) but this doesn't work. Here is the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.pipe(first()).subscribe(subscribeToData => {
        this.title = this.dataService.getData("...");
            this.anotherService.getData
                .subscribe(another => {
                    this.data = data;
                },
                ...
        });
    }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.pipe(first()).subscribe(subscribeToData => {
        let options = {
            data: {
            }
            ...
            {
            title: this.dataService.getData("...");
            },
            ...

        };
        ...

    });
}
```

If I remove subscribe from ngOnInit then ngAfterViewInit works fine, else it fails. So is there a way to subscribe two or more times from within the same component at the same time?

Here is the data service:

```
private dataSource = new ReplaySubject(1);
data$ = this.dataSource.asObservable();

loadData(... : void) {
    if (sessionStorage["data"] == null {
        this.http.request(...)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json()).subscribe(data => {
            ...
            sessionStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(this.data));
            this.dataSource.next(this.data);
            ...
        });
    } else {
        this.dataSource.next(this.data);
    }
}

getData(... : string){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to subscribe twice to an observable?

Comment: Because as you can see in my code, I need to use data from my data service on ngOnInit and on ngAftweViewInit. I'm new to rxjs, so this approach might be wrong. Don't hesitate to write me if you know a better solution.

Comment: `ngOnInit()` is the first life cycle hook - so it will always be executed first. Once you have *subscribed* to the observable in ngOnInit, you can store it in a variable and then use that in the ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do that?

Comment: @NicholasK How do I store the observable in a variable and reuse it?

Comment: Before that, any reason why you are using a ReplaySubject? I ask because it is causing a nested subscription in your component which isn't the best practice.

Comment: I was suggested to do that in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64560696/7061548

Comment: It was just a suggestion (from your previous question), *"...probably a ReplaySubject in this particular case"*. Unless you have a specific use case you don't really need it IMO.

Comment: @NicholasK But is it worth refactoring it? Will it solve my problem? If you can provide an answer that answers my question and solves my problem I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problems with double subscribe in your code - probably you are facing some asynchronous code issues. The browser is fast enough to quickly go through component's lifecycle and to quickly call `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`. Both of them will be executed almost simultaneously and lightning fast - definitely faster than a http call. In this case, in your `ngOnInit`'s subscribe you have another call that might be executed *after* the `ngAfterViewInit` (although I'm not sure).

Here is an example that shows that double subscribe in a single component works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/double-subscribe?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Try to refactor your logic to be more consecutive: if your `ngAfterViewInit` must be executed *after* all the asynchronous code in `ngOnInit` is done - store the result of the `ngOnInit`'s chain somewhere in a variable; if your `ngAfterViewInit` does not care about the `ngOnInit` try to avoid accessing the same variables, especially `this.data`.

Also try to avoid nested `subscribe`s - they can be replaced with `switchMap`/`flatMap`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.pipe(
      first(),
      tap(data => this.title = this.dataService.getData(data)), // note that this should be synchronous
      switchMap(data => {
        // another asynchronous call here
        return this.anotherService.getData(data)
      })
    ).subscribe(finalData => {
        this.data = finalData
    }
```

To refactor your `ngAfterViewInit` to be executed *after* `ngOnInit` do the following:

```
onInitData$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.onInitData$ = this.dataService.data$.pipe(
      first(),
      tap(data => this.title = this.dataService.getData(data)), // note that this should be synchronous
      switchMap(data => {
        // another asynchronous call here
        return this.anotherService.getData(data)
      }),
      shareReplay(1) // shareReplay(1) is important to avoid doing double http requests per subscribe
    );
  this.onInitData$.subscribe(data => console.log('data from ngOnInit', data));
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.onInitData$.pipe(switchMap(thatData) => {
     // will be executed only AFTER the ngOnInit is done
     return this.dataService.data$.pipe(first()).subscribe(subscribeToData => {
        let options = {
            data: {
            }
            ...
            {
            title: this.dataService.getData("...");
            },
            ...

        };
        ...

    });
  }).subscribe(dataFromAfterViewInit => {})
}
```

In general, you'd want to think why do you even need `ngAfterViewInit`? What do you want to achieve by splitting those calls between `onInit`/`afterViewInit`? Why do they access the same data in a component?

Comment: I think you are right, the error I get is this:
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: No mDatatable element exist.
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.mDatatable (<anonymous>:885:35)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (comp.component.ts:152)
    at ...

Maybe i could put ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit together, but i'm not sure if it will break anything.

Comment: I did some minor changes to your suggestioned code for the ngOnInit to make it work. But the code for ngAfterViewInit doesn't work. I can't apply it. I have tried to do several changes but nothing works. Are you sure that it is correct? I get errors like: "Cannot find name "thatData", "No overload matches this call..." and also other errors when I try to edit the code.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding a setTimeOut inside ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: @Fth you shouldn't copy my code "as is" because it was only an example. You had to change `thatData` variable to the one you have it your component (or provide a proper stackblitz example for me to fix your code)

Comment: `setTimeout` in `ngAfterViewInit` is **not** the correct approach - you should try to avoid it

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Yes I know, but as I wrote, I tried to make changes to it so it "fits" into my code and it worked for ngOnInit but not for the ngAfterViewInit. And im aware of how bad an approach using setTimeout is - but it fixed it. Okay, maybe i can put up a stackblitz example if you want to look at it :)

Comment: It's going to be hard to make a proper stackblitz example so I will just keep it as it is for now. Thank you for your help.